# Figure out if nodejs crashed

Tags: node.js, bash

Basically each time I want to push a change to my server I go through this workflow.:

```
node app.js
//if above not crashed
git push heroku <branchname>
git push origin <branchname>
```

I want to write a script that does all of this for me. I need to figure in the script if running node app.js crashes. How would I go about that?

**EDIT:**

Sam's answer below detects if node crashes, however if it doesn't it keeps running. I guess what I want is something like: start node. wait 30s. if still running, proceed with the rest of the script

Comment: What do you do manually to determine if your app has crashed?

Comment: check the console output. Node prints a stacktrace when that happens. When it doesn't crash I get an output saying something like "app running at port 3000"

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you mean by 'crash', but if there is an error from the node process you should have a non zero exit code, which you can test in your script:

```
#!/bin/bash
node app.js
if [ $? != 0 ] 
then
   echo "app.js failed; exiting"
   exit 1
fi
git push heroku branchname
# etc.
```

If you also want to detect the case where `node` terminates without error, but your script `app.js` has an error, make sure you `process.exit(code)` with a non-zero code.

Comment: thanks! I used `$?` when testing in my shell, and then typed it incorrectly

Comment: this properly detects node crashing. But it made me realize that if it doesn't crash the node process doesn't exit on its own. I edited the original question

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that node automatically launches in the background, so:

```
node app.js &
node_pid=$!
sleep 30

if kill -0 $node_pid 2>/dev/null; then
    # still running
    git push heroku $branchname
    git push origin $branchname
fi
```

Sending a process the `0` signal is a handy way to see if it's still alive.